# How to refresh a page without loading the page into the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a way to refresh/reload a page in ASP.NET without actually loading the page? I need the page to reload every 5 minutes but this will not be loaded by any user.

Thank you

Comment: "will not be loaded by any user" - in what sence? Some random code issues GET request? or you want automatic page refresh as suggested by Thomas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use ASP.Net Cache. Use the @OutputCache directive with a duration.

[Setting the Cacheability of a Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9s3a17d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Would this allow me to refresh the page without being loaded into the browser?

Comment: It caches the page say for 5 minutes, so any users who view the page in that 5 minutes will see a cache version. The page will get refreshed when another user views the page after the 5 minute duration has timed out. If you want a process happening each five minutes it maybe better to consider a Service or a Scheduled Task.

Comment: How can I create a Service or Scheduled Task?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way of doing it is to use a [html meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) that instructs the page to refresh after a given time interval (in seconds):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
```